# php-fpm and mkdir() permission denied - but libphp7-zts.so works fine

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, php, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have Concrete5 site which I need to move to php-fpm from libphp7-zts.

I've configured PHP-FPM as normal with Unix socket and PHP (for example "PHP info") is being served fine. I've made sure that PHP-FPM runs as "Apache" User and "Apache" Group (RHEL7).

Relevant config of php-fpm:

```
[www]

user = apache
group = apache

listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock

listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 0660

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/fpm/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/fpm/wsdlcache
```

Unfortunately, when application (CMS, Concrete5) tries to do anything on the content I'm getting "Permission Denied" - so as per title:

mkdir() Permission Denied.

Selinux is in permissive mode, permissions on files and folders seem to be OK as (now unsupported) libphp7-zts works fine.

Any ideas would be greatly appropriated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and corrected issue with this set up. This is the portion of the config to blame:

```
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/fpm/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/fpm/wsdlcache
```

so whatever you have in `php.ini` for `session.save_path`gets overwritten (so to speak) and needs correct permissions for the user which php-fpm runs to be able to write. In my instance I've matched that with php.ini config and that  seems to be working as expected.

Hope that helps